# Entity not saved on Junit

Tags: jpa, junit, transactions

Hello im getting trouble with my test code, it is simple but i cannot find out for 3 days.

so help me with it.

it runs on spring boot 3.2 and junit 5 and jpa..

here's my code

1. here's method that save data

```
    void readyDocument() {
        var article = monkey.giveMeBuilder(TranslationArticleEntity.class)
                .set("articleId", ARTICLE_ID)
                .set("title", INITIAL_TITLE)
                .set("authorId", USER_ID)
                .set("techTags", Set.of(TechTag.JAVA))
                .sample();
        translationArticleRepository.saveAndFlush(article);

        var versionContent = monkey.giveMeBuilder(TranslationArticleVersionContentEntity.class)
                .set("versionContentId", 0L)
                .set("articleId", ARTICLE_ID)
                .set("version", INITIAL_VERSION)
                .set("editorId", USER_ID)
                .set("content", INITIAL_CONTENT)
                .sample();
        versionContentRepository.saveAndFlush(versionContent);
    }
```

2. here's log database state

```
 @Transactional
    void doLog(){

        log.info("-----------------------DO LOG-----------------------------------");
        String transactionName = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName();
        boolean isActualTransactionActive = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();

        log.info("Thread: {}, Transaction: {}, Active: {}, TransactionManager: {}",
                Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                transactionName,
                isActualTransactionActive
              );
        var allTranslation = translationArticleRepository.findAll();
        var allVersions = translationArticleRepository.findAll();

        if(allTranslation.size()!= 1){
            log.info("T size : {} ", allTranslation.size());
            log.info("V size: {} ", allVersions.size());
            log.info("-----------------------DO LOG-----------------------------------");
            return;
        }

        log.info(" ------all data good -----");

        log.info("-----------------------DO LOG-----------------------------------");
    }
```

and here's a test code , i commented out other stuff.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@Slf4j
public class TranslationUpdateIT {
...
   @Test
    void concurrency_update__100_trial() throws InterruptedException {
         비동기_update_id_100회_시도() throws InterruptedException {
        // Given
        log.info("START!");
        readyDocument();
        log.info("sleep 1000 ms");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        doLog();
        log.info("END!");
        // When
        //asyncUpdateAndWait(ITERATION);

        // Then
        //checkVersions(ITERATION);

    }
...
```

When i see logs, in readyDocument(), it surely committed , but it is not shown on findAll() method on jpa repository

here's a debug log about this code

```
13:31:31.649 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - START!
13:31:31.667 [Test worker] WARN  c.n.f.a.g.SetContainerPropertyGenerator - Set of enum should not be bigger than enum size. enum size : 2
13:31:31.711 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
13:31:31.711 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(139196446<open>)] for JPA transaction
13:31:31.712 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@7f47a7e8]
13:31:31.712 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]
13:31:31.773 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]
13:31:31.773 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:31:31.773 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(139196446<open>)]
13:31:31.779 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(139196446<open>)] after transaction
13:31:31.783 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
13:31:31.784 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1855424604<open>)] for JPA transaction
13:31:31.785 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@249a58b6]
13:31:31.785 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]
13:31:31.792 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]
13:31:31.792 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:31:31.792 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1855424604<open>)]
13:31:31.797 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1855424604<open>)] after transaction
13:31:31.797 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - sleep 1000 ms
13:31:32.802 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - -----------------------DO LOG-----------------------------------
13:31:32.803 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - Thread: Test worker, Transaction: null, Active: false, TransactionManager: {}
13:31:32.806 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
13:31:32.806 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(846103603<open>)] for JPA transaction
13:31:32.822 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@1ae4c84d]
13:31:32.822 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
13:31:32.830 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
13:31:32.830 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:31:32.831 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(846103603<open>)]
13:31:32.839 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(846103603<open>)] after transaction
13:31:32.840 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
13:31:32.840 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1781082115<open>)] for JPA transaction
13:31:32.843 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3a63653b]
13:31:32.843 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
13:31:32.847 [Test worker] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
13:31:32.847 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:31:32.847 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1781082115<open>)]
13:31:32.853 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1781082115<open>)] after transaction
13:31:32.853 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - T size : 0 
13:31:32.853 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - V size: 0 
13:31:32.853 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - -----------------------DO LOG-----------------------------------
13:31:32.853 [Test worker] INFO  c.d.project.IT.TranslationUpdateIT - END!
```

let me know why i can not find data on findAll method.

it is same on i put Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW on each method

Comment: i use mysql docker image version is 8.0.36